# Rigging an MRI machine with club speakers and lights

Tags: electromagnetism, light, speakers, power-electronics

I'm using a magnetic resonance imaging ([MRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging)) machine to [fMRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_magnetic_resonance_imaging) trial subjects while they experience club-like conditions. This means I need loud, high-fidelity speakers, flashing multicolored lights from multiple directions, etc. Big speakers usually means big magnets, obviously a problem in an MRI machine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do Faraday cages work for magnetic waves? Otherwise, keep them as far away for the machine as possible, and crank up the volume a bit more. The field decays exponentially.

Comment: Not in an MRI machine. It uses superconductors to maintain the massive fields

Comment: Can't you just spill drinks on them?

Comment: MRI is Magnetic Resonance Imaging. It uses giant magnets to create fields which interact with polar molecules within body tissues, reading the tissues' effects on the fields to measure the tissues. Functional MRI, or fMRI is basically the same thing, except it measures activity in the brain during specific circumstances or while completing tasks

Comment: You've seen the [headphone solutions](http://www.medicalproductsdirect.com/mrihese.html)? Seems like you'd need headphones in any case. MRIs are [damn loud](http://youtu.be/6Aj2QspPf7s) themselves in a very non-techno way.

Comment: Have you looked at electrostatic speakers? They don't use magnets, but fall short in certain areas; such as price and bass response, however they may be suitable for your application.

Comment: I don't think you'll get a better answer than @Samuel's link. +1

Comment: Couldn't you just use the MRI as the magnet of the speaker, i.e. use a bare coil on a cone?

Answer (score 1):

One for the historians amongst us.

One of the companies I worked for (many years ago) was founded by a brilliant engineer by the name of (Sir) Charles Parsons. He invented many things but perhaps one of the strangest was the Auxetophone (originally patented by Short) - a compressed air gramaphone sold in the U.S. as the Victor Auxetophone. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_air_gramophone)

[image]

There's even a Youtube video for your entertainment.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7SV65DFNy8